# Windows 7 Admin Account Login

Tags: windows-7, security, file-management

I recently did a Clean Install of Windows 7 Professional on a new Harddrive.  I created one account, calling it Robert, and this account is of Admin type.   However, when ever I install software or access a folder on an old harddrive that contains photos, music, and the like, I get a message that I cannot access it, or cannot overwrite a txt file if I'm editing it...it just seems like this default admin account (Robert) still needs to take so many extra steps just to access data, modify documents, or whatever.   Is there any way to override this behaviour without having to go to each folder and change the security of it.  Shouldnt an Admin account be able to access any user files on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old hard drive still has ACLs (Access Control Lists) that limit access to the (non-existent) user from the old installation.

To check this, right-click a folder or file from the old hard drive, click properties, go to the Security tab, and check what you see.  If you don't see a Security tab, go to Folder Options and uncheck `Use sharing wizard (Recommended)`.

Comment: Thanks Ivo but this is the answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a Workgroup or Domain?

Since then the domain admin has to give your account admin rights